# Local and Staging Environments allow for updates, Live doesn't (and doesn't recognise the license.key)

Tags: license, updates

I'm just in the process of migrating a site from staging to live. I've pushed everything over and have copied/moved a license.key file from a site that we're no longer using to this one. However, when I log into the backend, I'm stll getting the `You’re running Craft Pro with a Craft Personal license.` message at the top. If I click on 'Resolve' - I get a spinner modal and nothing else happens, until eventually I get `An unknown error occurred`.

Running version `Craft CMS 2.6.2952`

I'm presuming it's not able to phone home for some reason to validate the license key - but I'm unsure what could be stopping it? Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I had disabled a few PHP functions as part of a security tweak.... I'm assuming it's using cURL to make the request to phone home.